# How to solve the issue of "CS8805: Program using top-level.." VS "1053: The service did not respond.."?

Tags: windows, service, worker

When the output type is set to "Windows application" or "Console application", the service can't be started and gives error "1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.". Digging behind that, I have found that it is due to Windows 10 (+ new Windows server versions) not allowing integration with the the UI (zero session) without the "Interactive Services Detection" service running - and that is not allowed in Windows 10.

Trying to solve that, using output type "Class library" instead, results in build error "CS8805: Program using top-level statements must be an executable.". I have read som articles saying that this can be due to a double semi-colon somewhere, but I haven't found anything like that in the source files.

So - how do I create a Worker service which is functional on Windows 10 and new Windows servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service can be a console or GUI .exe, it does not matter. However, it MUST call the service API when it starts:

> When the service control manager starts a service process, it waits for the process to call the `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` function. The main thread of a service process should make this call as soon as possible after it starts up (within 30 seconds).

Read more about services and look at the examples [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/using-services)...

Interactive services have been deprecated since Vista but some compatibility still remained for a while. That time is over, you just have to write a service and a helper app that runs in the user session.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try. But - if the worker service MUST call the service API, why isn't this part og the default code generated by the Worker Service template (VS 2022)?

Comment: Do you have a code example using this? Which file in the Worker template are you referring to?

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio so I don't know. I just know how to program a service.

Comment: As you did not tag your question with a language I can only guess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

Comment: Thank you Anders. This is exactly the tutorial I have used. I'll do it again from scratch. Maybe I missed something. Everything works as intended during debugging/manual execution. It's just getting it to start as a Windows Service.

Comment: I think it was some issues with the project file. I can get it to work now, but I can't get it to call my web service. Only when I debug it in VS. I'll create a new post for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the output type in your file.csproj by adding :

```
<PropertyGroup>
...
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I had the OutputType as Exe already. Added the second line, but nothing changed. I still get "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."